# Best DB for simple store app

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server, database, sqlite

I'm an engineering student, creating a proof of concept.

Basically, I will be creating an android app- but at this stage, I am deciding which database is best for me.

My app is very simple. It goes as follows:

- User opens app
- User creates an account   (the username/pw will be stored in the DB)
- User can 'browse' various product listings (no search functionality required)

The user will be shown a page with the following options:

- Sony TV
- Honda Civic
- iPhone 5
- etc

Clicking one of them will take the user to a 'details' page, where for example it will display:

- iPhone 5 (as well as a photo of the iPhone)
- Display:      4-inch
- Processor:    A6
- LTE:          yes
- Weight:       4 ounces

So basically, some basic data about the item the user chose. If it was a TV, it would show the relevant options (screen size, resolution, internet capabilities, etc).

So really, the DB needs to be able to:

- have user management capability
- store some info about some products (we're talking less than 100 total)
- store the photo of the related product

I am choosing between:

- Microsoft SQL Server
- MySQL
- SQLite

Please let me know if there is a better DB choice that I have missed...

Here is what I know so far:

Microsoft SQL Server:

- Free with my MSDN subscription

MySQL

- Free
- Hard to configure

SQLite

- Free
- No gui

I would prefer something that is easy to set-up, learn, and use. And with a GUI.

Please advise.

Comment: use a SQLite implementation.It's the main database provider used in ANdroid therefore finding examples and tutorial will be easy for you. Using the others might require either using customized connectors etc.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server has easily the best GUI of your three candidates.

But, I wouldn't try to make an android app with a Windows-only database.  SQLite seems like the best candidate for an android device.

Comment: What drawback(s) will exist if I were to make an android app with a Windows-only database?

Comment: The biggest drawback would be that you cannot run Windows on an Android device …

Comment: Oh, so you're saying it's not compatible?

Comment: Exactly.  You can't run SQL Server on android at all.  I'm not sure if you'd be able to make calls to a Windows-based SQL Server installation in a traditional client/server model, but I suspect you can't, and even if you could, it's probably WAY more complicated than just embedding SQLite on the android device itself.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the items can have different stats - e.g. TV will have different features to a Phone.

You should consider using a document database - something like MongoDB would suit you. This is free too, has a GUI, and best of all is extensible - you can 20 documents which have features of a TV and 40 different documents which have features of a phone.

You can try it out quite quickly here: `http://www.mongohq.com/home` although I recommend you install your own copy if you have your own server as it'll be cheaper for you.

I have to say, I love MySQL and SQL Server too - both are awesome. You can mimic the document store (sort of) in either of those by creating a table like this:

```
create table features(productid int, key nvarchar(100), value nvarchar(max))
```

This will allow you to store phone features, tv features etc in the same table and will allow you to extend this feature set infinitely without having to go back and modify the table definition every time.

Comment: Thank you! I am taking a look at MongoDB right now, I'll report back to you shortly.

Comment: So what do you think?